# How to do macroexpand-1 and macroexpand in MIT Scheme?

Tags: common-lisp, mit-scheme

In Common Lisp I can define a two-level macro and expand the macro like this:

```lisp
(defmacro calc (a op b)
  (list op a b))

(defmacro twice (x)
  (list 'calc x '+ x))

(twice 10)
(macroexpand-1 '(twice 10))
(macroexpand '(twice 10))
```

Output:

```
20
(CALC 10 + 10)
(+ 10 10)
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing in MIT Scheme:

```scm
(define-syntax calc
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ a op b)
     (op a b))))

(define-syntax twice
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ x)
     (calc x + x))))

(twice 10)
```

How can I do the equivalent of `macroexpand-1` and `macroexpand` in MIT Scheme?

Comment: You have looked at the manual? https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Racket, `macroexpand` would be

```
(syntax->datum
  (expand-to-top-form '(twice 10)))
;; '(+ 10 10)
```

and `macroexpand-1` would be

```
(syntax->datum (expand-once '(twice 10)))
;; '(calc 10 + 10)
```

There are papers for macro-debugging in scheme by M. Felleisen.
See [here](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/gpce07-cf.pdf).